# Enable extensions that come with vim-airline

Tags: vim, vim-airline

After I installed vim-airline, I found that there are a variety of plugins in the path

> vim-airline\autoload\airline\extensions

but only a part of them are loaded every time I start Vim.

How can I enable extensions such as syntastic, tagbar, unite, ctrlp and so on?

A possible way is to copy the .vim file to 'plugins' folder that vim provides. However, I want a solution that airline provides so that I don't have to manipulate files and can just configure them by a few commands.

Comment: I see this in airline's Readme
`vim-airline integrates with a variety of plugins out of the box. These extensions will be lazily loaded if and only if you have the other plugins installed (and of course you can turn them off).`

Comment: Yes, indeed. I read this before as well. But when I use command ':scriptnames' to see what have been loaded, only to find a few of them there. I don't know where goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been confused with how those extensions work for a few days.

It turns out that I have misunderstood what those extensions are.

**Extensions come with airline are not plugins themselves**, but some additional features related to those plugins to be displayed in the statusline.

That is to say, **one has to install those plugins first before he enables those extensions**. And after the installation of plugins, airline can work perfectly with them, providing cool style to display their status.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have in my old vimrc, it still seems to work:

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1

"" Whitespace Machine
"  enable/disable detection of whitespace errors.
let g:airline#extensions#whitespace#enabled = 1
```

I'd imagine you can enable other extensions with the same syntax.

(If you like a more fully-featured vim development enviroment -- check out [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs).)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This command makes tabline to work well. However, it doesn't apply to other extensions.